# Cocoa Objective C - How can i convert an array of images to a video file, and save it to disk?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, video

My Cocoa application is a socket server which receives video frame from my iphone, and displays them on the screen as a video.
I am saving every image in an array after i receive them.
Is there a way to convert this array of images to a video file and let the user to save this file to disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [`QTMovie`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in QTKit.framework. In particularly, once you've created a movie instance, you can use `-[QTMovie addImage:forDuration:withAttributes:]` to add a "frame" to the movie.

Comment: is it possible in cocoa touch?

Comment: All these methods are deprecated in OS X V10.9