# What is the best way to animate a sequence of images on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, animation, sequence

I am making a game that has a win state and a lose state. For each state, I would like to display a short animation of 2-3 seconds. The first animation consists of 60 PNGs, at a rate of 30 fps, and the second animation consists of 80 PNGs, also at 30fps. I have tried various methods, and searched extensively for a solution, but the top two results I keep finding are to use UIImageView animationImages and Core Animation. Using UIImageView works very nicely in the simulator, but takes forever to run the first time on the device. I figure this is because the images need to be loaded into memory. I am using "imageNamed" to populate the animationImages array, but I guess they need to be rendered the first time the animation is called? I have tried pre-rendering them when the app loads, and this seems to do the trick, but pre-rendering all those images takes nearly 10 seconds, which is not user friendly. I would also be open to using Core Animation, but I have very limited knowledge of it so a detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

when you say that I need to load everything at the app's startup, what exactly do you mean? Right now, I initialize both arrays of animation images when the app loads, like this:

```
// Create thinnestAnimation Array
thinnestAnimation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
{
    UIImage *thinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ThinnestJump_%d.png", i]];
    [thinnestAnimation addObject:thinImage];
}

thinAnimationImageView.animationImages = (NSArray *)thinnestAnimation;
thinAnimationImageView.animationDuration = 2.0;
thinAnimationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
```

thinAnimationImageView is an IBOutlet in my interface, and I call `[thinAnimationImageView startAnimating];` when I want to animate the sequence of images. This heavily lags on the first call, but is fine thereafter. Is there anyway to prevent it from lagging the very first time?

Comment: Sorry, animation is computationally expensive. Apple wrote UIImageView as well as possible. Use it.

Comment: Core Animation won't really help you if you have prerendered frames you just want to draw in sequence; it's more for animations that involve moving or transforming an existing image (or set of images) and/or adding certain kinds of special effects. Now, if the kind of visual you're going for fits that description, you could use CA instead of your image sequence.

Comment: You might also look into what you can do to optimize your images. Do they have alpha? Do they really need it? Is a large area of the screen changing every frame, or just a small part? Is it something that might work better as a video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageView`'s built-in animation features are a good way of doing it. However, you need to load everything before you need to animate, such as at the app's startup. If you need multiple different animations to be ready, load multiple UIImageView objects at startup and call the one you need later, with its `startAnimating` method.

There are other methods to animate as well, such as using Cocos2D which uses OpenGL for animation, much faster performance. But then you have build your app in a different framework altogether, which might be overkill depending on what else is going on in your app.

Comment: As far as loading the UIImageView objects at startup, I initialized them but the first run of the animations still lagged. So instead, I performed both of the animations in hidden views on startup, so they are good to go when the user uses the app. The only drawback is that it takes 6-8 seconds to load the app.

Comment: if you have an animation-heavy application, you may consider other libraries than UIKit, such as Cocos2D

Comment: it's just those two short animations

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by andrews  UIImageView has inbuilt property of animation

Like you have a array of image (imgarray) and a image view

For creating array of images

```
NSMutableArray *imgarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100]
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%d.png",i];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
  [imgarray addObject:image];
}
```

Then for animation

```
UIImageView *imgview;

imgview.animationimages=imgarray;
```

then set

```
 imgview.animationDuration=2.0;  //in seconds

     [imgview startAnimating];
```

stopanimating for stopping animation
and there is also a property for repeat count of animation

Hope This Helps.....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [this article](http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/) about using a CALayer to do animation with a sprite sheet. A layer has less overhead as does the spritesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I just dealt with this myself and found the following useful:

Bottom of the 3rd answer, [Animation using array of images in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040528/animation-using-array-of-images-in-sequence)

Basically, using imageNamed: performs slower than pulling your images directly from the bundle. Here's what I've done that's made mine load faster:

```
NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
{
    [imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pngSlice-%d", i]
                                                                                            ofType:@"png"]]];
}

self.myImageView.animationImages = imagesArray;
self.myImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
self.myImageView.animationDuration = 2.5;

[self.myImageView startAnimating];

imagesArray = nil;
```

This works if you add your images directly to the bundle and have them all named in sequence (i.e. pngSlice-0, pngSlice-1, pngSlice-2, ...). I had 150 images, change the conditional to match your image total.