# How to : Local MP4 Video as Background in iOS App Objective C iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ios8, background

I try to use a simple 13 sec mp4 video as background loop for my login screen.

I want the Video to autoplay and loop. It has no Audio and I don´t need controls.

I need buttons and other objects in front of it.

I tried to use a WebView and make the MP4 a GIF file from this Tutorial : https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2

But the problem is that my 5 MB MP4 has (converted to a GIF) a size of 95 MB.

I can´t use this method.

Is there any "Easy to Use" way ?

EDIT :

Okay this is what I did now.

I imported AVFoundation.

This is the Code in the View

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL* mURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"App-BG-Loop" withExtension:@"mp4"];

AVPlayer* player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:mURL];
player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[player currentItem]];

AVPlayerLayer* playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
playerLayer.frame = _videoView.bounds;
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
playerLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
[_videoView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

_videoView.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;

[player play];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.}

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
[p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];}
```

This works great in the iOS Simulator but when I try to start it on a device it wont start and or play the video. The View just stays white. No Error nothing.

Any Idea?

EDIT 2 :

Problem with not playing on device was the size of the video it was to big. Apple only supports 1080p on the devices.

Comment: Create a UIView animation of images. That's usually the easiest way

Comment: You may want to look into a better method of converting the mp4 into a GIF, as that is going to be a significantly easier process than dealing with looping video in the background. Or as @soulshined mentioned, create an animation with images to make your own gif (of sorts)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040528/animation-using-array-of-images-in-sequence

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try your ways tmrw maybe you can check my EDIT ?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to use an animation too. I tried it with a `UIImageView` first but the memory management was not too good with that. I ended up making a .mp4 from it and use it in a `MPMoviePlayerController`:

```
-(void)setupDashboardAnimation
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(checkMovieStatus:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"some_movie" ofType:@"some_extention"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];

    _backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    _backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    _backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    _backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    for (UIView *aSubView in _backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer.view.subviews)
    {
        aSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    [_backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer.view setFrame:imv_background.frame];
    [_backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer prepareToPlay];
}

-(void)checkMovieStatus:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (_backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer.loadState & (MPMovieLoadStatePlayable | MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) && _backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer.playbackState != MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
    {
        [self.view insertSubview:_backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer.view aboveSubview:imv_background];
        [_backgroundAnimationMoviePlayer play];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                        name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                                      object:nil];
        dashboardAnimationDidSetup = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its probably an UIImageView with a still from the video, so you don't see the video 'loading'